# Input focus loss due to whole template re-rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, jquery-templates

I've got a JQuery template like so:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input data-bind="value: ValueField, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />

    {{if $data.errors && $data.errors().length > 0 }}
    <div>
        an error occured
    </div>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

`$data.errors` is an `observableArray` that starts empty.

I have subscribed to `ValueField` and set `$data.errors` to `[ "hello" ]`. However when the `observableArray` is updated (because of the input change), the whole template refreshes, causing the input to lose focus.

The only difference in the DOM tree before and after is the `div` being added inside the if-block.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (using a regular `<!-- ko if: ... -->` data-bind): https://jsfiddle.net/at9y9ac8/1/ Any differences between your code and this fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Knockout *containerless control flow syntax* (based on comment tags) like so:

```
<div class="editor-field">
<input data-bind="value: ValueField, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />

<!-- ko if: $.isArray($data.errors()) && $data.errors().length > 0 -->
<div>
    an error occured
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```